# Alloy: HeaderView not rendering inside of TableView

Tags: uitableview, titanium, titanium-mobile

Please see my code below. A header does render in the table, but it's blank and not the proper height. I've tried Titanium SDK 3.0.2 and 3.1 and get the same results.

**view.tss:**

```
"#detail_header": {
    height: 200
}

"#search_icon": {
    top: 17,
    left: 14,
    image: "search_icon.png",
    width: 19,
    height: 23
}

"#search": {
    top: 0,
    left: 48,
    width: 599,
    height: 54,
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    font: {fontFamily: "Open Sans [Regular]", fontSize: "20"},
    autocapitalization: Titanium.UI.TEXT_AUTOCAPITALIZATION_WORDS,
    autocorrect: false,
    returnKeyType: Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_SEARCH
}

"#search_cancel_icon": {
    top: 19,
    left: 665,
    width: 22,
    height: 23,
    image: "textClear_icon.png",
    visible: false
}


"#horizontal_separator": {
    top: 55,
    left: 321,
    height: 1,
    width: 703,
    backgroundColor: "#e1e1e1"
}

".detail": {
    top: 0,
    left: 322,
    width: 703,
    height: Titanium.UI.FILL,
    separatorColor: "#ebebeb"
}
```

**view.xml:**

```
<TableView id="recipes" class="detail">
    <HeaderView id="detail_header">
        <ImageView id="search_icon" onClick="search_icon_click" />
        <TextField id="search" hintText="Search for a recipe" onChange="search_change" />
        <ImageView id="search_cancel_icon" onClick="search_cancel_icon_click" />
    </HeaderView>
</TableView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Im pretty sure the HeaderView property has to have one single view as its input:

```
<TableView id="recipes" class="detail">
    <HeaderView id="detail_header">
        <View>
            <ImageView id="search_icon" onClick="search_icon_click" />
            <TextField id="search" hintText="Search for a recipe" onChange="search_change" />
            <ImageView id="search_cancel_icon" onClick="search_cancel_icon_click" />
        </View>
    </HeaderView>
</TableView>
```